# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Pass Session data to Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, exception, layout

I want to show some data on every page with the layout (_Layout.cshtml), so I made a parent controller class, and the database access executes in its constructor. This works well except the case when I want to reach the session data, because when I try to check if the session variable exists, an exception (NullReferenceException) is thrown:

`if (Session["UserId"] != null)`

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think that's because the Session object doesn't exist yet in the parent class. I can't find out another soluton to pass session related data to the layout, only when I copy the code to all action controllers. Any ideas?

Update:
Dave A, here is the parent class:

```
public class PCMarketController : Controller
{
    protected PCMarketContext db = new PCMarketContext();

    public PCMarketController()
    {
        int numberOfCartItems = 0;
        if (Session["UserId"] != null) //Throws NullReferenceException in parent, works in action method
        {
            string UserId = HttpContext.Session["UserId"].ToString();
            List<CartItem> CartItems = db.CartItems.Where(i => i.UserId == UserId).ToList();
            foreach (var item in CartItems)
            {
                int count = item.Count;
                numberOfCartItems += count;
            }
        }
        ViewBag.NumberOfCartItems = " (" + numberOfCartItems + ")";
        List<Category> Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        ViewBag.Categories = Categories;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have yet to find a circumstance when Session Object hasn't been instantiated. I think It's available on Session_Start. Please share your 'parent controller class'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in assuming the reason for Session to be null. The session HttpContext.Session injected at a later time in the page life cycle by the ControllerBuilder.

I would usually override OnActionExecuting method of the controller for such a case (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.98).aspx).

One word of caution, using sessions may hinder the testability of your controller via standard unit tests

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, Your suggestion for overriding the OnActionExecuting method is exactly what I needed!